# is it because of the factorization of a morphism?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

From P309 of Rotman's Intro to Homological Algebra

Thm 5.91. *If *A* is an abelian category, then **Sh**(*X, A*) is an abelian category.*

The proof boils down to showing that monomorphisms $\varphi$ are kernels and epimorphisms $\psi$ are cokernels.

Rotman states that there is an exact sequence of sheaves

0 $\to$ *K* $\xrightarrow{\iota}$ *F* $\xrightarrow{\varphi}$ *G* $\xrightarrow{\nu}$ *K'* $\to$ 0.

If $\varphi$ is monic, then ker $\varphi$ = 0. And so 0 $\to$  *F* $\xrightarrow{\varphi}$ *G* $\xrightarrow{\nu}$ *K'* is an exact sequence in **Sh**(*X, A*). Hence there is an exact sequence
0 $\to$  *F$_x$* $\xrightarrow{\varphi_x}$ *G$_x$* $\xrightarrow{\nu_x}$ *K'$_x$* in *A*; that is im$\varphi$$_x$ = ker $\nu_x$ for all x. Therefore, $\varphi$ = ker $\nu$.

I'm not sure how the last "therefore" conclusion was reached. is it because $\varphi$ can be factorized as a composition of im$\varphi$ and cokernel(kernel$\varphi$)? I'm new to this, any help would be appreciated!